# ImportError : cannot import name <method> from <module> on linux

Tags: python, linux, module

I'm working on the implementation of an algorithm which was made to run on Windows and that I need to run on Linux now. It's written with Python 3.7 (but I made it run with Python 3.4 on windows and it worked).

Now, I'd like to run the algorithm on Linux as I said, however when I run the .py file that launches the whole algorithm, I got an error that says:

```
ImportError : cannot find name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/lib/Python-3.7.4/Lib/lxml/__init__.py)
```

I don't know how to resolve this error: the `lxml` library does exist to the indicated path and I installed Python 3.7 (because I originally tried to run it with Python 3.8, then tried 3.4 as it worked on Windows, but each time it couldn't find some method from one or another library...)

Comment: try creating a virtual env and install the libraries inside

Comment: `lxml` is a third-party library (i.e. not part of standard library), so you will need to manually download & install it on any system on which you wish to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the library as its not part of the standard Python library, you can install it using PIP by running the following command:

```
$ pip install lxml
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! If I run the command you shared, it returns : `Requirement already satisfied : lxlm in <PATH to python3.8>` but I think I need to install it in python 3.4. How can I specify which version of Python's lxml library to install ? (I have like 4 different versions of Python installed on my virtual machine...)